# React hooks JSX rendering not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have 5 card holders that are returned from an API and I need to render all 5 card holders but it is rendering only the first card holder. When I log the cardholders then it is logging arrays of 5 cardholders. But after I map through them and returns the JSX in my `renderCardHolders` it is only rendering the first returned user. Can some one help me with it?

```
function UserContainer (props) {
    const [cardHolders, setCardHolders] = useState([{}])

        useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchedData.map(user => {
            try {
                const uuid = user.Guid
                const response = Api.get(`/securityCenterApi/getCredentials/${uuid}`)
                .then(response => {
                    const cardHolderCredentials = response.data.Rsp.Result.Credentials    
                    const newGuid = Api.get(`/securityCenterApi/getUsers/${cardHolderCredentials}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        
                        const userName = response.data.Rsp.Result.Cardholder.Name
                        const bitLength = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.BitLength
                        const facilityCode = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.Facility
                        const cardNumber = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.CardId
                        
                        setCardHolders([{
                            username: userName,
                            bitLength: bitLength,
                            facilityCode: facilityCode,
                            cardNumber: cardNumber
                        }])
                    }
                    )
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        
        })
}, [props.fetchedData])

    // console.log(cardHolders)
    const renderCardHolders = () => {
        return cardHolders.map((cardHolder, index) => {
                console.log(cardHolder)
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <th>{cardHolder.username}</th>
                    <td>{cardHolder.bitLength}</td>
                    <td>{cardHolder.facilityCode}</td>
                    <td>{cardHolder.cardNumber}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th><abbr title="Position">Cardholder name</abbr></th>
            <th>Wiegand Bit type</th>
            <th><abbr title="Played">Facility Code</abbr></th>
            <th><abbr title="Won">Card number</abbr></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {renderCardHolders()}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    )
}

export default UserContainer
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked out the API calls, and everything seems to work.  However, while mocking it out based upon your code it looks like the first API call only returns a single user.  Do you mean to set state to an array of objects?  Something like:

```
setCardHolders(prev => [...prev, {
  username: userName,
  bitLength: bitLength,
  facilityCode: facilityCode,
  cardNumber: cardNumber
}])
```

Also, you probably want to initialize state with an empty array:

```
const [cardHolders, setCardHolders] = useState([]);
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-chandrasekhar-nxh9n?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function UserContainer(props) {
  const [cardHolders, setCardHolders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchedData.forEach((user) => {
      try {
        const uuid = user.Guid;
        console.log("uuid", uuid);
        Promise.resolve({
          data: { Rsp: { Result: { Credentials: "testcreds" } } }
        }).then((response) => {
          const cardHolderCredentials = response.data.Rsp.Result.Credentials;
          console.log(cardHolderCredentials); // Verify
          Promise.resolve({
            data: {
              Rsp: {
                Result: {
                  Cardholder: { Name: "Test Name" },
                  Format: {
                    BitLength: 1,
                    CardId: "CardId1",
                    Facility: "My Facility"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }).then((response) => {
            const userName = response.data.Rsp.Result.Cardholder.Name;
            const bitLength = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.BitLength;
            const facilityCode = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.Facility;
            const cardNumber = response.data.Rsp.Result.Format.CardId;

            setCardHolders((prev) => [
              ...prev,
              {
                username: userName,
                bitLength: bitLength,
                facilityCode: facilityCode,
                cardNumber: cardNumber
              }
            ]);
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }, [props.fetchedData]);

  // console.log(cardHolders)
  const renderCardHolders = () => {
    return cardHolders.map((cardHolder, index) => {
      console.log(cardHolder);
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <th>{cardHolder.username}</th>
          <td>{cardHolder.bitLength}</td>
          <td>{cardHolder.facilityCode}</td>
          <td>{cardHolder.cardNumber}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <abbr title="Position">Cardholder name</abbr>
          </th>
          <th>Wiegand Bit type</th>
          <th>
            <abbr title="Played">Facility Code</abbr>
          </th>
          <th>
            <abbr title="Won">Card number</abbr>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{renderCardHolders()}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <UserContainer fetchedData={[{ Guid: "1" }, { Guid: "2" }]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack! I had an issue in setting the setState into an array and your answer resolved the issue. Appreciated!

Comment: Hey Jack, while I was working on the above code it is keep adding cardholders to the previously rendered cardholders every time I click the button. Ex. 5 cardholders rendered after button is clicked. When I click the button again 5 cardholders are added to previous 5 cardholders so that total 10 cardholders are there. I need to re-render when I click the button

Comment: I'm not sure what button you are referring to, but it sounds like you are adding a new list of items to the existing list.  I would check your setState calls and make sure the logic is sound.

Comment: The button is in the parent component and thought I had it in the child component up there. Basically, if I click the button in the parent component the renderCardHolders function is executed again and instead of reload the page the fetched data is concatenated to the previous state. Believe something is wrong in my useEffect hook or something to do with setCardHolders()